# getting 403 in LinkedIN OAuth

Tags: php, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am getting this error

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 403, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect) at this line
$data = $oauthc->fetch($url, $body, $method, $headers);
```

while I use this code

```
try {
            $oauthc = new \OAuth(CUSTOMER_KEY, CUSTOMER_SECRET,
                OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1,OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI);
            $oauthc->enableDebug();
            $oauthc->setNonce(rand());

            $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/jobs';
            $body = file_get_contents('http://azaidi-usweb-08.vps.zulily.com/job.xml');
            $method = OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST;
            $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml');

            $data = $oauthc->fetch($url, $body, $method, $headers);


            $response = $oauthc->getLastResponse();
            $response_info = $oauthc->getLastResponseInfo();

            print "<pre>";
            print_r($oauthc->debugInfo);
            print_r($response);
            print_r($response_info);
            print "</pre>";

            exit;
}catch(OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($oauthc->debugInfo);
    print_r($e);
    exit;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before going deeper into this... the Jobs posting API program is only for selected partners. Has your company been accepted into this program? If not, you will not be able to post jobs regardless of whether we solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks I am not sure how to get my company accepted there

Comment: Read http://developer.linkedin.com/partner to learn more. I believe there's a minimum number of monthly jobs you need to be able to post as an initial screening criteria.